# Meteor template not reactive after using back button or Iron routing

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, iron-router

I have a simple template that shows a list of websites and a details page that allows users to post comments about the site. For some reason, when clicking the back button in the browser or Iron router link to another page then going back again the update function for the comments is no longer reactive. The collection is updated but not rendered to the template. No errors are thrown in the console.

I suspect an issue with my helpers but I'm a complete noob and have struggle for 7 or more days to understand meteor, mongo, react....after taking a short course on it....

My code to update the collection:

```
Template.website_details_form.events({
    "submit .js-add-comment": function(event) {
        var post, theID;
        post = event.target.post.value;
        theID = this._id;
        console.log("the post:" +post);  
        console.log("this is the id: " +theID);

        if(Meteor.user()) {     
             var user = Meteor.user().username;
             if (post != ""){
                 Websites.update({_id: theID}, {$addToSet:{comments:{user:user, comment:post}}});
                 $('input#post').removeClass('error');
             } else{
                 $('input#post').addClass('error');   
             }
         } else {
             swal("Please sign in to post!", "Oops...", "error");
         }      
         event.preventDefault();
     }
});
```

My helpers admittedly funky helpers:

```
var details_ID;
var thecomments; 
Template.website_details.helpers({
    sites:function() {      
        if(details_ID === undefined) {
            return Websites.find(
                { title: 'Goldsmiths Computing Department' });
        } else {            
           return Websites.find({_id:details_ID});
        }                
     }
}); 

Template.website_details_item.helpers({
    comments:function() {
        if(thecomments === undefined) {
            var c = Websites.find({title: 'Goldsmiths Computing Department'}).fetch();
            return c[0].comments;
         } else {
            return thecomments;
         }
     }
});

Template.website_details_form.helpers({
    identify:function(){
    if(details_ID === undefined){
        return Websites.find({ 
            title: 'Goldsmiths Computing Department' });
        } else {            
            return Websites.find({_id:details_ID});
        }            
     }
});
```

my router:

```
Router.route('/website_details', function () {
    this.render('navBar', {to: 'navbar' });    
    this.render('website_details', {to: 'main'});
});
```

I'm using a click function on a document to get the information for my vars that I used in the helpers....`this._id`,

I did see another question that specifically asked about reactivity after using the back button and iron routing, but that thread terminated at a github page with little interaction and addressed a issue I don't have...to my knowledge...I am a noob...Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you create a git so that we could test it?

Comment: Ok Thanks! I Cleaned up my helpers...finally understand how to use Sessions :) But I just can't get this event to re-render the template, ya know reactively... I'll post the Git soon as done.

Comment: @BlazeSahlzen I have finally created the git. This was/is a class project and I had to get as mush done as quickly as possible. The repo is at https://github.com/jjansa/meteor-reactive-issue

Comment: I tried out your code. In your `website_details` you are updating collections correctly but your helpers are reading the data from `Session` which is not getting updated.

Comment: Usually you want your helpers to read directly from the front-end database (which is reactively updated by the back-end database)

Comment: SOLVED!!! I just thought that about that right before making the git but.....thanks so much. Moved `Session.set()` to the the inside of the if block and tada! Thank you.

Comment: Cool! Might I add this as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: Yes! Please, do that.

Comment: Check my answer. I added more details for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/jjansa/meteor-reactive-issue/blob/master/client/main.js), I found that:

1. In the [`Template.website_details_form.events`](https://github.com/jjansa/meteor-reactive-issue/blob/master/client/main.js#L292), the `Websites` collection is getting updated correctly.

```
Websites.update({ // Saving to collection
   _id : theID
}, {
   $addToSet : {
      comments : {
         user : user, 
         comment : post
      }
   }
});
```

2. However, in the [`Template.website_details_item.helpers`](https://github.com/jjansa/meteor-reactive-issue/blob/master/client/main.js#L160), the comments data is being read from `Session` and not the `Websites` collection.

```
...
comments: function(){ 
   var post = Session.get('site'); // Reading from Session
   return post.comments;
},
...
```

**Two suggestions to fix this problem**:

1. When accessing the data from `helpers`, read it directly from the `Websites` collection:

```
var site_data = Websites.findOne({
   _id: someId
});

if(site_data) { // Check if comments_data is undefined
   return site_data.comment;
} else {
   return null;
}
```

2. When updating `Websites` collection, immediately update `Session` data:

```
Websites.update({ // Saving to collection
   _id : theID
}, {
   $addToSet : {
      comments : {
         user : user, 
         comment : post
      }
   }
}, function(err, data) {
      if(!err) {
         var site_data = Session.get('site');
         /* Modify site_data */
         Session.set('site', site_data);
      }
});
```

I would suggest the first option, as it avoids storing large amounts of data in the `Session` and because the client-side minimongo collection is already storing the same data.